# Why msvcrt.getch() is getting always same input without pressing any key on Windows

Tags: python

I am using Windows. I want take user input without pressing enter key and I found many examples, but somehow they are not working on me. I do not press any key and still msvcrt.getch() function is getting input(or atleast it is printing something) all the time. My code below:

```
import msvcrt
from time import sleep
while True:
    print(msvcrt.getch())
    sleep(1)
```

This is printing b'\xff' all the time. And if I press something, it does not care, it still print same string. I am using python 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. If using msvcrt: Code has to run in console. I was running that with IDLE.
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3ji6ew/ordgetch_returns_255_constantly/
Thanks to ingolemo.